# Css wiggle function not working

Tags: html, css

Hi guys trying to do this wiggle function from a website i found. However for some reason the wiggle function is not working. Any help on this matter would be great

I am using this website and i linked it like i was told and put the right code into CSS [Site](http://csshake.surge.sh/)

I am trying to make it look like CSSHAKE SLOW MINIFIED

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

```
<a href="http://csshake.surge.sh/" class="wiggle">Find Out More > ></a>

    .wiggle{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        font-size: 46px;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-family: amatic sc,cursive;
        color: Red;
        -webkit-animation: wiggle 0.5s infinite;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes wiggle {
        0% {
            -webkit-transform:rotate(4deg);
        }
        50% {
            -webkit-transform:rotate(-1deg);
        }
        100% {
            -webkit-transform:rotate(4deg);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/0f2qstq0/

```
<a class="btn shake-slow" href="#" >CSShake slow (735 B)</a>
```

Make sure to include this in your `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://csshake.surge.sh/csshake-slow.css">
```

Just add the `class='shake-slow'` to whatever element you want to 'shake'. This links the CSS to your element.